# Layout focusable before descendant clearFocus not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, focus

I've got a form layout looking like.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

           <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small" />

                    <Button
                        style="@style/Button.Small"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                            android:inputType="text" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                            android:inputType="text" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

I want to clear the focus of an EditText when the user clicks on the windows so I implemented the code below

```
     /**
     * Clear the edit text focus if the touch is outside its limits
     *
     * @param context  the activity context
     * @param editText the edit text
     * @param event    the motion event
     */
    public static void clearEditTextFocusOnMontionEvent(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull EditText editText, @NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            editText.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            if (!outRect.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
                editText.clearFocus();
                hideKeyboard(context, editText);
            }
        }
    }
```

But the focus is not going to the LinearLayout every time. THe focus is gained by the first visible EditText (exception when the header TextView is visible, the focus is gained by the LinearLayout).

I expected the focus to always be gained by the LinearLayout since its focusability is beforeDescendants.

Same goes when acionDone is clicked, I want the focus to be removed from the current EditText, so I implemented

```
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            WindowsHelper.hideKeyboard(context, view);
            view.clearFocus();
        }
```

but again the focus is gained by the first visible EditText.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

**Add below lib in your gradle**

compile 'com.yinglan.keyboard:hidekeyboard:0.0.2'

**add below code in onCreate method**

HideUtil.init(this);

**and setFocus true to your parent view**

Comment: That's just hiding keyboard, not clearing focus which is the main issue here

Comment: Do you mean you dont want to get focus while opening you actvity?

Comment: No, I want the focus to be removed from the EditText when the user touch outside (and no be gained by an other EditText)

Comment: then setFocus true to your parent view and use above lib to hide keyboard.

Comment: That is not the question. I would like to understand why my code is not working. Since the parent has android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" I expected it to take the focus but it's not what is happening.